# Using data from one data set to extract information from a different data set

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two datasets. One has information for each subject's health. The other has information for a before and after MRI date. I am trying to extract health information based on these pre/post dates.

## MRI Pre/Post data set:

```
ID  prescan PreDate Postscan    PostDate
5006    1   5/10/2018   1   6/14/2018
5007    1   5/15/2018   1   6/13/2018
5009    1   5/9/2018    1   6/11/2018
5011    1   5/31/2018   1   7/2/2018
5013    1   5/30/2018   1   7/5/2018
```

## Sleep data sample:

```
SubID   SleepDate   Day of Week RHR HRV Recovery
5007    5/12/2018   'Saturday ' 63  95  65
5007    5/13/2018   'Sunday   ' 66  72  52
5010    5/7/2018    'Monday   ' 74  40  48
5010    5/8/2018    'Tuesday  ' 68  67  59
5010    5/9/2018    'Wednesday' 75  74  82
5010    5/10/2018   'Thursday ' 71  80  89
5010    5/11/2018   'Friday   ' 71  91  95
5010    5/12/2018   'Saturday ' 68  66  58
5008    5/7/2018    'Monday   ' 60  132 85
5008    5/8/2018    'Tuesday  ' 60  123 90
5008    5/9/2018    'Wednesday' 66  105 68
5009    5/7/2018    'Monday   ' 47  148 90
5009    5/8/2018    'Tuesday  ' 45  169 87
5009    5/9/2018    'Wednesday' 46  176 75
5009    5/10/2018   'Thursday ' 50  138 54
5009    5/11/2018   'Friday   ' 46  132 42
5009    5/12/2018   'Saturday ' 47  158 60
5009    5/13/2018   'Sunday   ' 47  141 54
5006    5/7/2018    'Monday   ' 56  92  65
```

## What I tried (and variations of this)

```
SleepData %>%
  subset(SubID == 5006) %>% 
  filter(SleepDate %in% MRI_date$PreDate)
```

The above often returns all the 5006 ID data

```
SleepData %>%
  subset(SubID == 5006) %>% 
  subset(SleepDate == MRI_date$PreDate)
```

Which returns:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthLength of logical index must be 1 or 31, not 44Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

## what I am trying to extract

Based on this, for example:

```
If ID == 5009 & (Date == 5/9/2018 & 6/11/2018)
```

I would like to receive sleep data accordingly:

```
SubID   SleepDate   Day of Week RHR HRV Recovery
5009    5/9/2018    'Wednesday' 46  176 75
5009    6/11/2018   'Wednesday' 76  196 95
```

[I made up the 6/11/2018  for reference]

Comment: Try this `library(data.table);setDT(SleepDate)[MRI_date, on = .(SubID = ID, SleepDate > PreDate, SleepDate <=PostDate)]`  but before that convert the dates column to `Date` class with `as.Date`

Comment: Have you tried joining the two dataset on Id and SubId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the sleep data for each PreDate and each PostDate, it will make things simpler to gather those two dates into a single column, and to track which kind of date it is in another column. Then you can do a join to pull in all the sleep data that matches that ID and that date.

```
library(tidyverse)
MRI_date %>%
  gather(status, SleepDate, c(PreDate, PostDate)) %>%
  left_join(SleepData, by = c("ID" = "SubID", "SleepDate"))

#Joining, by = "SleepDate"
#     ID prescan Postscan   status  SleepDate Day_of_Week RHR HRV Recovery
#1  5006       1        1  PreDate 2018-05-10        <NA>  NA  NA       NA
#2  5007       1        1  PreDate 2018-05-15        <NA>  NA  NA       NA
#3  5009       1        1  PreDate 2018-05-09   Wednesday  46 176       75
#4  5011       1        1  PreDate 2018-05-31        <NA>  NA  NA       NA
#5  5013       1        1  PreDate 2018-05-30        <NA>  NA  NA       NA
#6  5006       1        1 PostDate 2018-06-14        <NA>  NA  NA       NA
#7  5007       1        1 PostDate 2018-06-13        <NA>  NA  NA       NA
#8  5009       1        1 PostDate 2018-06-11        <NA>  NA  NA       NA
#9  5011       1        1 PostDate 2018-07-02        <NA>  NA  NA       NA
#10 5013       1        1 PostDate 2018-07-05        <NA>  NA  NA       NA
```

---

Source data:

```
library(dplyr)
MRI_date <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F, colClasses = c("integer", "integer", "character", "integer", "character"),
  text = "ID prescan PreDate Postscan    PostDate
5006    1   5/10/2018   1   6/14/2018
5007    1   5/15/2018   1   6/13/2018
5009    1   5/9/2018    1   6/11/2018
5011    1   5/31/2018   1   7/2/2018
5013    1   5/30/2018   1   7/5/2018") %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, lubridate::mdy)


SleepData <- df <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F, 
  text = "SubID   SleepDate   Day_of_Week RHR HRV Recovery
5007    5/12/2018   'Saturday ' 63  95  65
5007    5/13/2018   'Sunday   ' 66  72  52
5010    5/7/2018    'Monday   ' 74  40  48
5010    5/8/2018    'Tuesday  ' 68  67  59
5010    5/9/2018    'Wednesday' 75  74  82
5010    5/10/2018   'Thursday ' 71  80  89
5010    5/11/2018   'Friday   ' 71  91  95
5010    5/12/2018   'Saturday ' 68  66  58
5008    5/7/2018    'Monday   ' 60  132 85
5008    5/8/2018    'Tuesday  ' 60  123 90
5008    5/9/2018    'Wednesday' 66  105 68
5009    5/7/2018    'Monday   ' 47  148 90
5009    5/8/2018    'Tuesday  ' 45  169 87
5009    5/9/2018    'Wednesday' 46  176 75
5009    5/10/2018   'Thursday ' 50  138 54
5009    5/11/2018   'Friday   ' 46  132 42
5009    5/12/2018   'Saturday ' 47  158 60
5009    5/13/2018   'Sunday   ' 47  141 54
5006    5/7/2018    'Monday   ' 56  92  65")
SleepData <- SleepData %>% mutate(SleepDate = lubridate::mdy(SleepDate))
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally swapped the names in the source data sets. Should be fixed.

Comment: So I keep getting a merged file that has the sleep and pre/post like  yours shows but then it includes every sleep data not just the ones that match..

Comment: Sorry, accidentally took out "SleepDate" from the `left_join` -- fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
library(dplyr)

sleep.dat %>%
 inner_join(mri.dat, by = c("Id" = "subId") %>%
 select(Id == "5009") %>%
 mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
 filter(Date >= as.Date("5-9-2018") & Date <= as.Date("6-11-2018")) %>%
 select(Id, SleepDate, `Day of Week`, RHR, HRV, Recovery)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the merge function:

```
    pre <- subset(merge(SleepData, MRI_date, by.x = c("SubID", "SleepDate"), by.y = c("ID", "PreDate")), TRUE, select = c(SubID:Recovery))
    post <- subset(merge(SleepData, MRI_date, by.x = c("SubID", "SleepDate"), by.y = c("ID", "PostDate")), TRUE, select = (SubID:Recovery))
    result <- rbind(pre, post)
```

The subset function is only used to pick the relevant columns from SleepData after the merge function with the `select =` argument - it does not remove any rows. This ensures that `rbind` only gets two data frames with same columns as arguments